# Visualize a matrix using geom_violin() in r

Tags: r, violin-plot

I have a correlation matrix (200x200) in the form of:

```
 >cormat

          n1              n2              n3  
 n1    1.000000000   0.132555050     0.009169320    
 n2   -0.121419322   1.000000000    -0.174995204    
 n3   -0.259331076  -0.171652163     1.000000000
```

Etc.

I want to visualize the distribution of the correlation between the columns in the data frame, for which this matrix has been created, using **single violin plot**. After typing this code:

```
 ggplot()+geom_violin(aes(c(cormat[1:200,]), c(cormat[,1:200])))
```

I got:

[image: Violin plot of correlation matrix]

Is it a possible result? Is there a better way to plot matrix using geom_violin()?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your correlation matrix. Shouldn't the diagonals all be 1 and the matrix be symmetrical?

Comment: You're right! I didn't want to show more crucial data, so I made up a few names, but, indeed, I have to correct the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help to make something a bit more representative:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(69)
df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 1/33 * 1:10 + rnorm(10), c = -(1:10) * 0.1 + rnorm(10),
                 d = 1/5 * 1:10 + rnorm(10), e = rnorm(10))
cormat <- cor(df)
```

Now in your example, since `cormat` is 500 square, `c(cormat[1:500,])` is the same as `c(cormat[,1:500])`, which are both the same as `c(cormat)`, that is, just `cormat` unrolled into a 250,000 length vector. Your plot is really just a density plot of all the correlation values. I'm not sure how useful this is:

```r
ggplot() + geom_violin(aes(c(cormat), c(cormat)))
```

[image]

You could instead do a plot of all the correlations separately as violin plots:

```r
plot_df <- reshape2::melt(cormat)
ggplot(data = plot_df) + geom_violin(aes(Var1, value, fill = Var1))
```

[image]

but this won't work well for 500 variables.

A more standard way to represent a correlation matrix this big would be as a correlation plot, like:

```r
ggplot(plot_df) + geom_tile(aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value))
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2020-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>